# Redirect non-www and HTTP to www and HTTPS

Tags: node.js, express, dns, redirect

I am running an Express web server. I used Let's Encypt to create SSL certificates for both the www and non-www version of my domain. My DNS has these records:

```
CNAME | Host: @   | Target: dynamicdns.example.com. | TTL: 60min
CNAME | Host: www | Target: dynamicdns.example.com. | TTL: 60min
```

I also have this node.js code to run the webserver:

```
// Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

// Create express instance
const app = express();

// Get credentials from system
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem', 'utf8');
const ca = fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem', 'utf8');
const credentials = {
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate,
    ca: ca
};

// Initalize server
app.use(express.static('public'));
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

// Listen for HTTP
httpServer.listen(80, () => {
    console.log('HTTP Server running on port 80');
});

// Listen for HTTPS
httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
    console.log('HTTPS Server running on port 443');
});
```

This all works correctly, but it creates an issue with having multiple valid URLs for the same content. The following URLs are all valid right now:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

I want to redirect all the wrong URLs to `https://www.example.com`, which is the correct URL. I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I highly recommend you look into doing that with a reverse proxy such as `Nginx` instead.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a middleware like this one, to check all domains and redirect accordingly:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.url);
  }
  next()
})
```

Just make sure to use it just for production

Comment: This doesn't switch from non-www to www

Comment: just add another if before the next to check the www part and redirect accordingly

```
if ( req.get('host').search(/^www/) !== -1 ) {
  return res.redirect( 'https://www.example.com' + req.url);
}
```

Comment: @JulianLachniet is my answer clear enough or you still have any doubts? also... the recomendation in the comment at the top is pretty valid, for better performance you would like to pute an Nginx at the top to handle the SSL and redirect to the proper domain instead of having Node doing this, here are some articles that could help you with that: 

https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (req.headers.host.slice(0, 4) === "www.") {
        if (req.secure) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.redirect(301, "https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
        }
    } else {
        res.redirect(301, "https://www." + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});
```

This is an example using TypeScript.

I prefer to use redirect with HTTPS code 301 that tells the browser to change the saved url to the correct.